# PowerShell ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, powershell, listener, tnsnames

I have an issue with a PowerShell script that i am running. This script uses ODAC (oracle data access components) to connect to an oracle database and obtain some values.

I've recently had to change the port number i use in sql developer to connect to the database.

However, when i've tried to change this port number in my powershell script i get an error

**ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor**

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Which provider do you used from ODAC? (it delivers several)

Comment: hi Wenfried. It's ODAC 11.2 64 bit

Comment: Which provider/driver? "ODBC", "OLE DB", "ODP.NET" or "ODP.NET Managed Driver"?

Comment: hi Wenfried. It's ODP.Net. I'm creating a .net object in powershell

Answer (score 0):

I use the following :

I install *ODAC1120320Xcopy_x64.zip* in `C:\oracle` (see newer versions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html))

Here is a snipet `ExecuteReader()` you can also use `ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
# Load Oracle assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\oracle\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"

$compConStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.213.6.15)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=OURSERVICENAME)));User Id=User;Password=Pass;Pooling=False"
# Establish the connexion
$oraConn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($compConStr)
$oraConn.Open()

$sql1Tpl = @"
  SELECT masi.yyyy as TYPE_ID FROM xxxx masi
  WHERE masi.serno = '{0}'
"@

$sql1 = $sql1Tpl -replace "blabla"

# Exécution
$command1 = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql1,$oraConn)
$command1.CommandTimeout = 1500
$reader1 =$command1.ExecuteReader()

$clocationID = $null
if ($reader1.HasRows -eq $true)
{
  $read =$reader1.read()
  if ($read -eq $true)
  {
    $clocationID = $reader1["C_LOCATION_ID"]
  }
}
# Close the reader
$reader1.close()

# Disconect
$oraConn.Close()
```